# How to line break in RMarkdown Displayed Equation Chunk

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am new to RMarkdown and I have the following I am knitting into PDF

```
$$

log( \text{employed}) = \beta_0 + \beta_1*log( adult \ wage ) + \\  
\beta_2*jobs \ created+ \beta_3*jobs \ destroyed + \beta_4*mw + \\  
\beta_5*teen \ pop + \beta_6*teen \ wage* \mu_i + \delta_{it} + \alpha_{it} + \kappa_{ir} 

$$
```

While the display that appears under this chunk projects the line breaks correctly, the output file has the equation run off the margins

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this solution?

```
 header-includes:
 - \usepackage{amsmath}
```

---

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
log( \text{employed}) = \beta_0 + \beta_1*log( adult \ wage ) + \\  
\beta_2*jobs \ created+ \beta_3*jobs \ destroyed + \beta_4*mw + \\  
\beta_5*teen \ pop + \beta_6*teen \ wage* \mu_i + \delta_{it} + \alpha_{it} + \kappa_{ir} 
\end{split}
\end{equation}
```

[image]

or this:

```
\begin{gather}
log( \text{employed}) = \beta_0 + \beta_1*log( adult \ wage ) + \nonumber \\  
\beta_2*jobs \ created+ \beta_3*jobs \ destroyed + \beta_4*mw +  \\  
\beta_5*teen \ pop + \beta_6*teen \ wage* \mu_i + \delta_{it} + \alpha_{it} + \kappa_{ir} \nonumber
\end{gather}
```

[image]

Second looks cooler ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is more of a LaTeX question than an RMarkdown one.

I'm actually surprised it's rendering your display like you want *at all* -- LaTeX doesn't usually like having line breaks inside the displaymath environments. I'm also surprised that your document is successfully knitting for that same reason, but I guess you're knitting to HTML which is apparently a bit more forgiving than knitting to PDF.

At any rate, here is a possible fix:

```
\begin{align*}
log( \text{employed}) & = \beta_0 + \beta_1*log( adult \ wage ) + \\
& \qquad \beta_2*jobs \ created+ \beta_3*jobs \ destroyed + \beta_4*mw +  \\
& \qquad \beta_5*teen \ pop + \beta_6*teen \ wage* \mu_i + \delta_{it} + \alpha_{it} + \kappa_{ir} 
\end{align*}
```

Changes:

1. Replace the $$ displaymath environment with `align*`, which will give you better control over the left/right alignment. (The `*` character instructs TeX not to number this equation for you.)
2. Use the `&` character to control how things should be aligned from left to right. The `\qquad` will add a bit of padding to offset the continuing lines to the right, which is the typical thing to do for expressions that extend over multiple lines.

Now, some further suggestions that I didn't implement above:

3. Consider replacing your original `log` with `\log` for nice typsetting of that function.
4. Consider adding a `\text{...}` wrapper around all your variable names (e.g. `adult wage`, `jobs created`, etc.) to make them look nice as well. You'll want to remove the `\`  spacing if you do this. Parentheses around these names may help readability when the name includes a space, or you could join the names with an underscore character (`\_` in text mode).
5. (This one is **extremely** nitpicky:) Notice that the spacing on the `+` characters at the ends of your lines aren't quite right -- this is because LaTeX doesn't recognize that there's anything being added, because there's nothing on the right side of the operator. We can fix this by adding a bit of space before `+` with `\:`, i.e.

```
... *\log(\text{adult\_wage}) \: + \\
```

**EDIT**: After reflecting on tpetzold's answer, I realized I should change the alignment keys: the second and third lines should start to the *right* of the equals sign, *and* should be offset to the right a bit for visual distinction.

Comment: i believe knitr to html uses mathjax so that could be why it works

Comment: This is what happens when you try to teach yourself. Through your help I'm one step closer to mastery!

Comment: Great, three people doing almost the same in parallel, and each with some additional ideas. It seems I was the slowest ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I would use an `align*` environment in this case, that allows alligned or multiline equations. The `*`suppresses the equation numbers. In addition I made a backslash in front of the `\log`, added `\_` and used `\cdot`instead of a multiplication `*` and finally placed the `+` at the begining under the `=`.

```
\begin{align*}
\log(\text{employed}) & = \beta_0 + \beta_1 \cdot \log( adult\_wage )\\  
                       & + \beta_2 \cdot jobs\_created + \beta_3 \cdot jobs\_destroyed + \beta_4 \cdot mw\\  
                       & + \beta_5 \cdot teen\_pop + \beta_6 \cdot teen\_wage \cdot \mu_i + \delta_{it} + \alpha_{it} + \kappa_{ir} 
\end{align*}
```

[image]

You may also consider to typeset multiletter variables upright as text or to remove redundant `\cdot` multiplication operators if you want.